# How to handle props injected by HOC in React with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created a simple HOC that inject a method `translate` in a component.

```
export interface IMessageProps {
  translate: (key: string) => string;
}

export const message = <P extends object>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<P & IMessageProps>
): React.SFC<P & IMessageProps> => (props: P) => {

  const translate = (key: string): string => messages[key];

  return <Component {...props} translate={translate}/>;
};
```

Usage:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<IMessageProps, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <>{this.props.translate('hello.world')}</>
    );
  }
}

export default message(MyComponent);
```

The issue come when i want to call my component `<MyComponent/>` because tsc complains that the property `translate` is not passed to `MyComponent` and expect something like `<MyComponent translate={...}/>`.

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IMessageProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IMessageProps'.
    Property 'translate' is missing in type '{}'.
```

So my question is: **how to bypass this fake error ?** I don't want to make `translate` optional in `IMessageProps` because tslint will complains about `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit**

Typescript 3.2 breaks the code below. Until 3.2 spread operations with generic type parameters were not allowed except for jsx tags and were not very tightly checked there. This [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28234) changes this. Spread operations are not more tightly checked and the this breaks out code. The simplest adjustment we can make is to use a type assertion on `props` :

```
export const message = <P extends IMessageProps>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.SFC<Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof IMessageProps>>> => (props: Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof IMessageProps>>) => {

    const translate = (key: string): string => messages[key];

    return <Component {...props as P} translate={translate} />;
};
```

**Before 3.2**

You can just exclude the properties of `IMessageProps` from the returned `SCF` using `Pick` to pick properties from `P` and `Exclude` to exclude the keys of `IMessageProps`

```
export interface IMessageProps {
    translate: (key: string) => string;
}

export const message = <P extends IMessageProps>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.SFC<Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof IMessageProps>>> => (props: Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof IMessageProps>>) => {

    const translate = (key: string): string => messages[key];

    return <Component {...props} translate={translate} />;
};


class MyComponent extends React.Component<IMessageProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <>{this.props.translate('hello.world')}</>
        );
    }
}

const MyComponentWrapped = message(MyComponent);

let d = <MyComponentWrapped /> // works
```

**3.5 and above**

You can use `Omit<P, keyof IMessageProps>` instead of `Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof IMessageProps>>`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you ! As a workaround I also make it work by casting the export: `export default message(Install) as React.ComponentType<{}>`.

Comment: @AlexandreAnnic Yeah, that also works if you have no extra properties, but if your component actually has extra properties you would need to specify them again. `Pick<P, Exclude<..>>` works for any `P` :)

Comment: Yes it was clearly a workaround. Not a real solution. Finally I did a mistake when defining my wrapper: I could solve my problem simply by removing `IMessageProps` from `React.SFC<P & IMessageProps>`.

Comment: this does not seem to work with typescript 3.2.4 :( 
Typescript is complaining that `Type '{ translate: (key: string) => string; }' is not assignable to type 'P'`
I'm looking for a solution and will share it here if I find one.

Comment: @Logar 3.2 seems to break the code Probably https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28234 in particular

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks for that quick reply. I'm not good enough with typescript to understand the least bit of that pr, is this the intended behaviour to break the sample code you did, or is it a bug ?

Comment: @Logar Edited and added a 3.2 solution. It's the inteneded behavior, spreads operations are better typed now but this also leads to new errors. In this particula case we will need a type assertion unfortunately

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for this. I'm trying to type a generic context consumer injector, I'll see if I manage to do it with your update

Comment: @Logar if not, ask a question, someone will answer ;)

Comment: Will definitely do, and will notify you here if I do ;) For now, I casted my spreaded props as any because I don't have the generic types in function implentation, and mostly because it's late friday... thanks again anyway

Comment: It doesn't work for me with TypeScript 4.1.2. I get errors for `<Component />` in HOC:

`Type 'Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, "translate">> & { translate: (key: string) => string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, "translate">> & { translate: (key: string) => string; }' is not assignable to type 'P'.
    'Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, "translate">> & { translate: (key: string) => string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'MessageProps'.`

Comment: Sorry, I was inattentive. I should specify `...props as P` like it's in "Edit" section of the answer: `<Component {...props as P} translate={translate} />`.