# React Native - Higher Order Component with ref callback in TypeScript throws compile error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, higher-order-components

### Intro

I am trying to create a `Higher Order Component` for a `Dialog` component in `React Native`. Sadly, I have some compile errors that I do not understand at all. I have followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb) on `Higher Order Components` in `TypeScript`, but it does not show an example for getting `ref` to work.

### Setup

I have a component called `DialogLoading`, and I export it through a `Higher Order Component`  called `withActions`. The `withActions`component defines two interfaces, to determine what props it injects and what additional props it takes in. In the following code, the type parameters `C`, `A` and `P` stand for `ComponentType`, `ActionType` and `PropType` respectively.

The interfaces are:

```
interface InjectedProps<A> 
{   onActionClicked: (action: A) => void;}
```

and

```
interface ExternalProps<C, A>
{   onActionClickListener?: (component: C | null, action: A) => void;}
```

I also declare a type alias that denotes the final props type for the `HOC`. This type should have all the props of the wrapped component, all the props of the `ExternalProps<C, A>` interface, but not the props of the `InjectedProps<A>` interface. This is declared as follows:

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type Subtract<T, K> = Omit<T, keyof K>;

type HocProps<C, A, P extends InjectedProps<A>> = Subtract<P, InjectedProps<A>> & ExternalProps<C, A>;
```

The `Higher Order Component` is then declared as follows:

```
export default <C, A, P extends InjectedProps<A>> (WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
{
    const hoc = class WithActions extends React.Component<HocProps<C, A, P>>
    {
        ...Contents of class removed for breivity.

        private onActionClicked = (action: A) =>
        {
            this.onActionClickedListeners.forEach(listener => 
            {   listener(this.wrapped, action);});
        }

        private wrapped: C | null;

        render()
        {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent ref={i => this.wrapped = i} onActionClicked={this.onActionClicked} {...this.props} />
            );
        }
    }

    return hoc;
}
```

and can be used by:

```
<DialogLoading onActionClickListener={this.onActionClickListener} title="Loading Data" section="Connecting" />;
```

### The Problem

On the ref callback inside the render function of the `HOC`, `TypeScript` gives me the following error messages:

```
[ts] Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InjectedProps<A> & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
[ts] Type 'Component<P, ComponentState, never> | null' is not assignable to type 'C | null'.
     Type 'Component<P, ComponentState, never>' is not assignable to type 'C'.
```

I suspect this is because the `WrappedComponent` that is passed in, is of type `React.ComponentType<P>`, which is a union type of `React.ComponentClass<P>` and `React.SFC<P>`. The error is thrown, because the stateless components in React do not accept a ref callback. A possible solution would then be to change it's type to be **just** `React.ComponentClass<P>`.

This *kind of* fixes the problem, but strangely enough, a new error is now thrown on the `onActionClicked` prop of the wrapped component! The error is:

```
[ts] Type '(action: A) => void' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<P, ComponentState, never>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<P>)["onActionClicked"]'.
WithActions.tsx(7, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onActionClicked' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<P, ComponentState, never>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<P>'
```

This second error baffles me completely. What makes it **even stranger** is that when I adjust the type alias for the `HocProps` to the following (i.e. I no longer Subtract `InjectedProps<A>` from `P`):

```
type HocProps<C, A, P extends InjectedProps<A>> = P & ExternalProps<C, A>;
```

The error on `onActionClicked` is removed! This seems strange to me, because the type definition of `HocProps` has nothing to do with the prop type of the wrapped component! This "solution", however, is undesirable to me, because now the `InjectedProps<A>` are injectable by the user of the `HOC` as well.

### The Question

So where am I going wrong here?

- Am I correct in assuming the ref callback did not work because the `Wrapped Component` type was `React.ComponentType<P>` instead of `React.ComponentClass<P>`?
- Why does changing the `Wrapped Component` type to `React.ComponentClass<P>` result in a compile error on the `onActionClicked` prop of the `Wrapped Component`?
- Why does changing the type alias for `HocProps` remove said error on the `onActionClicked` prop? Aren't they completely unrelated?
- Is the `Subtract` functionality I've cooked up correct? Is that where the errors are coming from?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, so thanks in advance!

Comment: [This bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27385) is part of the problem.  I will write more if I have a chance.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Matt McCutchen! I'd love to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct in assuming the ref callback did not work because the `Wrapped Component` type was `React.ComponentType<P>` instead of `React.ComponentClass<P>`?

Roughly speaking, yes.  When you make a JSX element from the `WrappedComponent`, which has a union type (`React.ComponentType<P> = React.ComponentClass<P> | React.StatelessComponent<P>`), TypeScript finds the props type corresponding to each alternative of the union and then takes the union of the props types using subtype reduction.  From [checker.ts](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/0a97663843e11f745d9998d54db0970ee3bfb748/src/compiler/checker.ts) (which is too big to link to the lines on GitHub):

```
    function resolveCustomJsxElementAttributesType(openingLikeElement: JsxOpeningLikeElement,
        shouldIncludeAllStatelessAttributesType: boolean,
        elementType: Type,
        elementClassType?: Type): Type {

        if (elementType.flags & TypeFlags.Union) {
            const types = (elementType as UnionType).types;
            return getUnionType(types.map(type => {
                return resolveCustomJsxElementAttributesType(openingLikeElement, shouldIncludeAllStatelessAttributesType, type, elementClassType);
            }), UnionReduction.Subtype);
        }
```

I'm not sure why this is the rule; an intersection would make more sense for ensuring that all required props are present regardless of which alternative of the union the component is.  In our example, the props type for `React.ComponentClass<P>` includes `ref` while the props type for `React.StatelessComponent<P>` does not.  Normally, a property is considered "known" for a union type if it is present in at least one constituent of the union.  However, in the example, the subtype reduction throws out the props type for `React.ComponentClass<P>` since it happens to be a subtype of (have more properties than) the props type for `React.StatelessComponent<P>`, so we're left with just `React.StatelessComponent<P>`, which does not have a `ref` property.  Again, this all seems weird, but it produced an error that pointed to an actual bug in your code, so I'm not inclined to file a bug against TypeScript.

> Why does changing the `Wrapped Component` type to `React.ComponentClass<P>` result in a compile error on the `onActionClicked` prop of the `Wrapped Component`?

The root cause of this error is that TypeScript is unable to reason that the combination `onActionClicked={this.onActionClicked} {...this.props}` of type `Readonly<HocProps<C, A, P>> & { onActionClicked: (action: A) => void; }` provides the required props type `P`.  Your intent is that if you subtract `onActionClicked` from `P` and then add it back, you should be left with `P`, but TypeScript has no built-in rule to verify this.  (There is a potential issue that `P` could declare an `onActionClicked` property whose type is a subtype of `(action: A) => void`, but your use pattern is common enough that I expect that if TypeScript were to add such a rule, the rule would hack around this issue somehow.)

It's confusing that TypeScript 3.0.3 reports the error on `onActionClicked` (though this may be due to the issue I mentioned).  I tested and at some point between 3.0.3 and 3.2.0-dev.20180926, the behavior changed to report the error on `WrappedComponent`, which seems more reasonable, so no further follow-up is needed here.

The reason the error *doesn't* occur when the `WrappedComponent` type is `React.ComponentType<P>` is because for a stateless function component (unlike a component class), TypeScript only checks that you pass enough props to satisfy the constraint of the props type `P`, i.e., `InjectedProps<A>`, not actually `P`.  I believe this is a bug and have [reported it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27385).

> Why does changing the type alias for `HocProps` remove said error on the `onActionClicked` prop? Aren't they completely unrelated?

Because then `{...this.props}` by itself satisfies the required `P`.

> Is the `Subtract` functionality I've cooked up correct? Is that where the errors are coming from?

Your `Subtract` is correct, but as described above, TypeScript has very little support for reasoning about the underlying `Pick` and `Exclude`.

To solve your original problem, I recommend using type aliases and intersections instead of subtractions as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528669).  In your case, this would look like:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface InjectedProps<A> 
{   onActionClicked: (action: A) => void;}

interface ExternalProps<C, A>
{   onActionClickListener?: (component: C | null, action: A) => void;}

// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528669 for full explanation.
const hocInnerPropsMarker = Symbol();
type HocInnerProps<P, A> = P & {[hocInnerPropsMarker]?: undefined} & InjectedProps<A>;

type HocProps<C, A, P> = P & ExternalProps<C, A>;

const hoc = <C extends React.Component<HocInnerProps<P, A>>, A, P>
    (WrappedComponent: {new(props: HocInnerProps<P, A>, context?: any): C}) =>
{
    const hoc = class WithActions extends React.Component<HocProps<C, A, P>>
    {
        onActionClickedListeners;  // dummy declaration

        private onActionClicked = (action: A) =>
        {
            this.onActionClickedListeners.forEach(listener => 
            {   listener(this.wrapped, action);});
        }

        private wrapped: C | null;

        render()
        {
            // Workaround for https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27484
            let passthroughProps: Readonly<P> = this.props;
            let innerProps: Readonly<HocInnerProps<P, A>> = Object.assign(
                {} as {[hocInnerPropsMarker]?: undefined},
                passthroughProps, {onActionClicked: this.onActionClicked});
            return (
                <WrappedComponent ref={i => this.wrapped = i} {...innerProps} />
            );
        }
    }

    return hoc;
}

interface DiagLoadingOwnProps {
    title: string;
    section: string;
}

// Comment out the `{[hocInnerPropsMarker]?: undefined} &` in `HocInnerProps`
// and uncomment the following two lines to see the inference mysteriously fail.

//type Oops1<T> = DiagLoadingOwnProps & InjectedProps<string>;
//type Oops2 = Oops1<number>;

class DiagLoadingOrig extends React.Component<
    // I believe that the `A` type parameter is foiling the inference rule that
    // throws out matching constituents from unions or intersections, so we are
    // left to rely on the rule that matches up unions or intersections that are
    // tagged as references to the same type alias.
    HocInnerProps<DiagLoadingOwnProps, string>,
    {}> {}
const DialogLoading = hoc(DiagLoadingOrig);

class OtherComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    onActionClickListener;
    render() {
        return <DialogLoading onActionClickListener={this.onActionClickListener} title="Loading Data" section="Connecting" />;
    }
}
```

(Here I've also changed the type of `WrappedComponent` so that its instance type is `C` so that the assignment to `this.wrapped` type-checks.)

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks a lot for the thorough explanation. The line `instead of declaring a type variable for the inner props type and defining the outer props type by excluding things, declare a type variable for the outer props type and define the inner props type as an intersection` in your other answer has removed the error from my code. Sadly, now the `onActionClicked` prop is usable by the end-user of the HOC. Have I misunderstood something about what you meant? If we return a `ComponentType<P>`, `P` will always include the `InjectedProps`, right? Whether we `P extends InjectedProps` or `&`.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you tried, but I went ahead and added my version of the solution.  Let me know if you have further issues or questions.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks again for all the effort. In your example, the end-user is still able to do the following: `<DialogLoading onActionClicked={(_: any) => {}}   />;`. I.e. the user of the HOC can still specify `onActionClicked` on the final HOC component. I remain uncertain as to how to prohibit this.

Comment: There were several mistakes in my code; I thought I tested that it type-checked but apparently not.  Sorry.  Please try the updated version.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, thanks Matt! It's the middle of the night here, and I wont have time to properly test this out until wednesday. If everything works out by then, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks again for all your diligent work! As a side node, I don't quite understand the comment on the "fragile" TypeScript rule you mention in your solution. If you could enlighten slightly on that, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I realized that a trick I recently added to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528669) to solve a different problem will also solve this "fragility" problem.  I've added the trick here, added some explanation to the other answer, and added an example here of how the "fragility" problem can manifest if the trick isn't used.

Comment: Your answer seems to be working! Thanks a lot for the help, I'll mark your answer as accepted!