# Typescript: Remove an attribute from an object safely

Tags: typescript

I'd like to write a typescript function that takes an object that includes the parameter `foo` and outputs the same object without the parameter `foo`.  I want to do this all in a typesafe manner.  Seems pretty simple, but I'm stumbling.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
interface FooProp {
    foo: string;
}
type WithFooProp<P extends object> = P extends FooProp ? P : never;
type WithoutFooProp<P extends object> = P extends FooProp ? never: P;

function withoutFooProp<P extends object>(input: WithFooProp<P>): WithoutFooProp<P> {
    // How do I get rid of these any's
    const {foo, ...withoutFoo} = input as any;
    return withoutFoo as any;
}
```

This isn't great because I use `any` a bunch.  I'd sorta expect the code to work as is without `any`, but TS complains that `input` isn't an object and can't be destructured.  How could I improve this method?

In addition, when I use this function, TS forces me to provide the generic types explicitly.  I wish it would infer the types implicitly. Is there any way I could write the function to implicitly grab the parameters.

```
// Compiles - but I have to specify the props explicitly
withoutFooProp<{foo: string, bar: string}>({
    foo: 'hi',
    bar: 'hi',
});

// This doesn't compile - I wish it did!  How can I make it?
withoutFooProp({
    foo: 'hi',
    bar: 'hi',
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can let the parameter type be simply `P`, where `P` is constrained to contain the `foo` property, so that type inference will work: it will just set `P` to the argument type.  Then use [`Pick`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/8a166ad95905f56170c8b35c4ab7e5dfa2a32358/pages/Utility%20Types.md#picktk) and [`Exclude`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/8a166ad95905f56170c8b35c4ab7e5dfa2a32358/pages/Utility%20Types.md#excludetu) to generate the type of the output object containing all properties of `P` except `foo`.

```
interface FooProp {
    foo: string;
}
type WithoutFooProp<P> = Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, "foo">>;

function withoutFooProp<P extends FooProp>(input: P): WithoutFooProp<P> {
    const {foo, ...withoutFoo} = input as any;
    return withoutFoo;
}
```

You won't be able to get rid of the `any` unless/until [this suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727) is implemented.  I wouldn't worry about it.

This `withoutFooProp` function should work on any concrete input type and give you a concrete output type.  If you are using `withoutFooProp` on objects of generic types, then you may run into problems because of TypeScript's limited ability to reason about `Pick` and `Exclude`, and you may wish to use intersections instead (even though doing so is technically unsound), as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528669) in the context of React higher-order components.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this typesafe function which works as generic and can be used for any object:

```
export function deleteProperty<TObject, TProp extends keyof TObject>(object: TObject, prop: TProp): Omit<TObject, TProp> {
 const {
    [prop]: toDelete,
    ...newObject
 } = object

 return newObject;
}
```