# React HoC inject props with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-intl, high-order-component

I have a react HoC which is add two params (function to translate and current locale) into component props. It's works good. But i start rewrite project with TypeScript, and i have no idea how to do that.

My point is very similar as [how-to-handle-props-injected-by-hoc-in-react-with-typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083920/how-to-handle-props-injected-by-hoc-in-react-with-typescript). But i have one more HoC into my HoC.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl';

export function withTranslate(Component) {
  function WithTranslate(props) {
    const { intl, ...compProps } = props;
    const translate = key => {
      return intl.formatMessage({
        id: key
      });
    };

    return <Component {...compProps} t={translate} locale={intl.locale} />;
  }

  WithTranslate.displayName = `withTranslate(${Component.displayName ||
    Component.name}`;
  WithTranslate.propTypes = {
    intl: PropTypes.shape({
      locale: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      formatMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }).isRequired
  };
  return injectIntl(WithTranslate);
}
```

injectIntl from "react-intl" have typings

```
interface InjectedIntlProps {
    intl: InjectedIntl;
}

interface InjectIntlConfig {
    intlPropName?: string;
    withRef?: boolean;
}

function injectIntl<P>(component: React.ComponentType<P & InjectedIntlProps>, options?: InjectIntlConfig):
React.ComponentClass<Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof InjectedIntlProps>>> & { WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P & InjectedIntlProps> };
```

I try to do this with

```
interface WithTranslateProps {
  t: (key:string) => string;
  locale: string;
}

export function withTranslate<T extends object>(Component:ComponentType<T & WithTranslateProps>):
  ComponentType<T & WithTranslateProps> {
  function WithTranslate<P>(props:P & InjectedIntlProps) {
    const { intl, ...compProps } = props;
    const translate = (key:string) => {
      return intl.formatMessage({
        id: key
      });
    };

    return <Component {...compProps} t={translate} locale={intl.locale} />;
  }

  WithTranslate.displayName = `withTranslate(${Component.displayName ||
  Component.name}`;

  return injectIntl(WithTranslate);
}
```

It's not working.

> TS2322: Type '{ t: (key: string) => string; locale: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>
> TS2322: Type 'ComponentClass, any> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType'.
>     Type 'ComponentClass, any> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass'.
>       Type 'Component, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Component'.
>         Types of property 'props' are incompatible.
>           Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly'.
>             Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.

Can anyone help me?